# JUnit or TestNG for Sauce Labs tests?

Tags: junit, testng, saucelabs

We currently use JUnit for testing, but this will be our team's first try at paralleling the tests.

Would there be a major advantage to moving using TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any specific advantage of using TestNG in preference of JUnit with regards to the parallelizing of tests.  It's pretty straightforward to get tests to run in parallel using either library, and we have created a [sample test](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/blob/sauce_java-2.1.9/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/junit/WebDriverParallelWithHelper.java) for JUnit that demonstrates how to run the tests in parallel.

The Sauce TestNG samples also demonstrate how to configure the tests to run in parallel, which is done via the [XML configuration file](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/blob/sauce_java-2.1.9/testng/src/test/resources/xml/WebDriverTest.xml).

We have also created a [ConcurrentParameterized](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/com/saucelabs/junit/ConcurrentParameterized.java) test runner for JUnit, which will supports running parameterized tests in parallel.